# USER field in ps command(android env)

Tags: linux, android, process, ps

In android environment,

What does USER in the ps command indicate?

```
ps
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
root      1     0     748    608   c0267708 0001b95c S /init
```

Here are the various values that i see in system.

```
smartcard
u0_axxx
system
root
```

What do they signify? In particular I am interested about system.

I have read the man page of ps but could not find information. I also tried to google. Did not help me much.

Answer (score 1):

Every process on a modern computer is executed by a "user", and the kernel tracks who is executing it. In this case, the user is not a person operating the computer, but an identity under which services and os processes are run.

`ps` lists the processes running on a system. the process you have indicated is the init process, which loads and maintains the operating system components and services.

Each os uses non-interactive users differently. for instance linux runs many system-space processes as root or as a specific user created specifically for the service, whereas windows does so via the NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM account, or accounts like LOCALSERVICE, NETWORKSERVICE, etc. if you look at a windows system with process explorer, or a linux system with ps or top, you will see many processing running in the background from many differant users. Android is a heavily modified linux kernel, so its the same way.

In android, the System account is simmilar to the linux root account, but with some differances. see here for some details on them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933108/what-s-difference-between-android-system-user-and-linux-root-user